# Obtener una respuesta con AJAX jQuery, no va a succes!

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

realizo esta consulta de jQuery AJAX, porque estoy haciendo una prueba de PHP, AJAX, JQUERY, El asunto es que intento realizar una petición al servidor de enviar datos de los campos de usuario y contraseña pero al momento de enviar los datos, siempre se me va a error en vez de success, en $.ajax(), Nosé que pasa aquí?

```js
//Codigo jQuery 3.3.1

$('#send').click(function(){

 $.ajax({
  method:'post',
  url:'login.php',
  datatype: 'html',
  data: user : {$('#user').val()},
  success : function(response){
   $('.alertArea p').text(response);
  },
  error : $('.alertArea p').text("Hubo un error al enviar los datos.!");
 });

});
```

```css
/*Codigo CSS */

*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
input{
 padding: 10px;
}
h2{
 font-family: "trebuchet ms";
}
.alertArea{
 display: none;
}
.alertArea p{
 background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!-- Codigo HTML -->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stl.css">
 <title>Formulario de imagenes</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form method="post" align="center" id="form">

  <h2>Inicie sesión</h2>
  <hr>
  <br>

  <div class="alertArea">
   
   <p></p>

  </div>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" name="user" id="user">

  <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass">

  
  <button id="send">Enviar</button>
 </form>

 <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 

include('conexion.php');

$usuario = $_POST['user'];
$contrasena = $_POST['pass'];


echo "Los datos son : 'Usuario : $usuario' , 'Contrasena : $contrasena'";?>
```

Añado que el botón estando dentro del form me recarga la pagina, pero cuando lo coloco fuera del form no me recarga la página, y eso que quité el action="" , de verdad nosé como evitar que recargue la página también, me imagino que eso es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas en tu código. Voy a tratar de darte una mano.

Enumero por partes lo que he visto de forma global y luego aporto un código como solución:

### Javascript

- Conviene encerrar todo el código dentro de `$(function() {` (es el sustituto del conocido document.ready
- Para que no recargue la página, puedes pasar el evento en parámetro y usar `preventDefault`
- Usaremos `done` y  `fail`, porque `success` es obsoleto desde jQuery 3.
- No importa que quites el action, lo que cuenta es el parámetro `url` que pones en Ajax
- Tu parámetro `data` de Ajax es erróneo. Además, no estás pasando el valor de `pass` que intentas recuperar en PHP

Propongo estas correcciones:

```
$(function() {

    $("#send").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data= {user : $('#user').val(), pass : $('#pass').val()};
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: data,
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('.alertArea p').text(response);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
        });

    });
});
```

---

### HTML

Supongo que necesitarás pasar la contraseña, entonces agrega un id a ese input, para que se pueda recuperar en la variable `data` que ya viste más arriba.

```
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="pass" id="pass">
```

---

### PHP

Verifica que los datos se pasaron en el POST.  Aunque mucha gente usa `isset`, mi preferido para esto es `empty`, combinado con un operador ternario que me permite guardar los datos de forma definitiva en una variable.

Eso permite además aplicar el principio básico de *no crees nada hasta que no estés seguro de que vas a necesitarlo*.

```
<?php 
    /*Había un error aquí, olvidé poner el signo ?*/
    $usuario    = ( empty($_POST['user']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['user'];
    $contrasena = ( empty($_POST['pass']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['pass'];

    if ($usuario && $contrasena){
        /*Sólo aquí estamos seguros de necesitar la conexión*/
        include('conexion.php');
        $msg="Los datos son : 'Usuario : $usuario' , 'Contrasena : $contrasena'";
    }else{
        $msg="No se postearon datos de usuario y contraseña";
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: Hola.! , Primero presenté un problema con NULL, me decía Syntax error, unexpected 'NULL', pues lo quito, y esta vez si se dirige en request.done pero la respuesta del php es del else : else{
        $msg="No se postearon datos de usuario y contraseña";
    } , no me recibe esos datos el php...

Comment: @Abdiel perdona, es que cometí un error, en PHP ponlo así y prueba de nuevo: `$usuario = ( empty($_POST['user']) ) ?  NULL : $_POST['user']; $contrasena = ( empty($_POST['pass']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['pass'];` me faltó este símbolo`?` en ambos para que el temario funcione.

Comment: Hola amigo.! pues gracias, si solucionó, enrealidad tenías ese problemita allí con el "?" ya lo coloqué, y funcionó.! aunque me funcionó sin eso también , pero me imagino que es mucho mejor así, enrealidad me ayudastes con jQuery que el success no me enviaba los datos pues por la version que estaba usando y pues con .done() me sirvió perfectamente, gracias , ahora intentaré insertar usuarios existentes en una tabla, Si se me da las dudas en eso pronto postearé, por lo demás muchas gracias una vez más por tu tiempo y buena intención. :D

Comment: @Abdiel, me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar el que se recargue la pagina puedes usar `submit` de jquery y manejar como quieres que se procese la forma. `preventDefault()` evitara que se realice la acción por default de la forma.

```
    $( "#form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "Submit de #form se ha lanzado" );
      //Aqui la logica para manejar la forma.
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Para el asunto de que el ajax no entra a success creo que no es tan fácil diagnosticar sin mas información, siempre puedes ver el error que la función regresa con el callback de `error`

```
$.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url:'login.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {user : $('#user').val()},
    success : function(response){
        $('.alertArea p').text(response);
    },
    error: function(response){
        $('.alertArea p').text("Hubo un error al enviar los datos.!");
        //imprime a consola el response con detalles del error
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Aunque a simple vista veo unos detalles unos typos en el ajax `datatype` deberia ser `dataType` y solo deberia haber un objeto en el campo de `data`. Y no se la configuracion de mostrar los errores en PHP pues tu codigo va a generar un NOTICE al no existir el valor de `$_POST['pass']`

Comment: Gracias, pero enrealidad mi problema es que no puedo usar success ya que la versión de jquery 3.3.1 lo tiene obsoleto, por lo que tuve que usar .done() , de igual forma gracias.!